# Valor do Id não está mudando no ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, crud

Estou criando um CRUD em ASP.NET no meu projeto, porém, começou a dar um problema. Quando eu tento excluir um Produto, ele passa o Id totalmente diferente para a outra View, um Id que não corresponde ao valor atribuído. Por conta disso, não consigo excluir o produto desejado. Já tentei mudar o Id pela View, como é mostrado no código a seguir

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Produto", new { id=item.idProduto })" 
    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm active">
    Editar
</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Produto", new { id=item.idProduto })" 
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm active">
    Excluir
</a>
```

Mas nada mudou, continua com o mesmo problema. Esse código se localiza na View que lista todos os dados do Produto. O código da ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var objproduto = new Produto();
    objproduto.idProduto = id.ToString();
    return View(objproduto);
}

// POST: Categoria/Delete/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Produto produto)
{
    if (produto.idProduto != null)
    {
        var objproduto = new Produto();
        objproduto.DeleteProduto(produto);

        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Boa noite Leo, a sua View é tipada? Da onde vem o "item.idProduto"? Uma outra observação é... O aconselhável é que o id seja um inteiro e não uma string. Pois assim o banco consegue auto incrementar o valor de forma automática. Tente mudar isso tb. Não acho que isso seja erro, mas é uma boa prática.

Comment: Sim, é uma View tipada. item.idProduto vem do próprio Model, onde `item` seria a variável no Model. Sim, realmente eu também considero um número inteiro bem melhor para representar um identificação, começarei a utilizar ao invés de uma String. Sabe qual é o real problema? É que ele está trazendo o Id de outro dado, que no caso é a IdCategoria, é como se ele simplesmente ignorasse o IdProduto e pegasse apenas o IdCategoria

Comment: Seu código de cara já me preocupa onde a camada de negócio está misturada com a passagem de mensagem, métodos em classes que deveriam somente passar mensagem ... !!! Enfim tem como colocar todas as classes envolvidas, mas, de cara o seu código revela grande problemas